# Find text on page that is dynamically generated

Tags: jquery, asp.net, database, find

I have a page that pulls its content from a database using repeaters in ASP.NET. The page is a FAQs page with jQuery UI Accordions as well. Now I was wondering if it is possible to search the page and find text that the user enters inside the accordions. I have seen on Stack a way to search using JavaScript but my issue is that it doesn't search inside the accordions when they are closed. Is this even possible? Thank you!
- Dan

Here is an excerpt from my ASP.NET page...

```
  <h2 id="general" class="modelHeading">General Questions</h2>
        <asp:Repeater id="rptGenQA" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
          <div>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="ques">
        <h4 class="question"><%#Eval("question")%></h4>
        <div><%#Eval("answer")%></div>
          </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <div style="text-align: center">
          <a href="#top">All Products FAQs Index</a>
          </div>
        </div>             
      </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
  <h2 id="188" class="modelHeading">Model 188</h2>
        <asp:Repeater id="rptModel_188" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
          <div>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="ques">
        <h4 class="question"><%#Eval("question")%></h4>
        <div><%#Eval("answer")%></div>
         </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
          <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;">
          <a href="/model/188/">Back to Model 188</a> 
          <a href="#top">All Products FAQs Index</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
```

And my JavaScript so far...

```
$(function() {
  var icons = {
    header: "plusmark",
    activeHeader: "negmark"
  };

$(".ques").accordion({
    header: '.question',
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content",
    icons: icons,
    animate: 500
});


});
```

The accordions are closed by default which is my issue. How do I find content in the accordions and have them open and jump to that section.

Comment: please post some sample html to better illustrate what you want

Comment: closed is irrelevant assuming text is there and depending on what you want to do with it. Please provide more details

Comment: why can't you just use javascript? `var txt = document.getElementById("id").innerHTML;`